# Arrarylist size is 0 with static recyclerview list in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code Adapter I was defined a list when I am debugging the code it is giving me size of the patient is 0.Now all the list items are set to recyclerview to display list of item .but nothing is displaying

Actually model class contains a data.but its is giving me as 0

Can any one help me to reslove it.

list_item.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/bg"
    android:id="@+id/contact_card"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/card_details">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/cards"
                android:background="@color/bg">


                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/slivergray"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                    app:cardElevation="4dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/suject_ids"
                        android:background="@color/white">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
                            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                android:id="@+id/doctor_profile"
                                android:layout_width="96dp"
                                android:layout_height="96dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_round_account_circle_24"
                                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                                app:civ_border_color="@color/theme"/>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                                android:orientation="vertical">
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/doctor_name"
                                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/names"
                                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                    android:text="Dr. Regina Joseph"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                                    android:textColor="@color/theme"
                                    android:textSize="14sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Booking : Scheduled"
                                        android:padding="2dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/theme">

                                    </TextView>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/age"
                                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/doctor_name"
                                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                    android:text="Age : 26"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/theme"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Booking ID: 10"
                                        android:padding="2dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/theme">
                                    </TextView>
                                </LinearLayout>
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/date"
                                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/doctor_name"
                                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                    android:text="Today,25 Dec"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/theme"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />
                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/time"
                                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/doctor_name"
                                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                    android:text="11:00 - 11:15 AM"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:textColor="@color/theme"
                                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:weightSum="2"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="View Details"
                                        android:layout_below="@+id/consultationFees"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                                        android:textColor="@color/theme">
                                    </TextView>
                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Cancel Appointment"
                                        android:id="@+id/select"
                                        android:padding="5dp"
                                        android:layout_below="@+id/consultationFees"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                                        android:gravity="right"
                                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                                        android:textColor="@color/theme">
                                    </TextView>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PatientAdapter.java:

```
public class PatientAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PatientAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<PatientModel> patientModels;

    public PatientAdapter(List<PatientModel> patientModels) {
        this.patientModels=patientModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PatientAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        mContext = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_list, parent, false);
        PatientAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new PatientAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PatientAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.doctor_name.setText(patientModels.get(position).getPatient_name());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("size of the patient", String.valueOf(patientModels.size()));
        return patientModels.size();

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView doctor_name;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            doctor_name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.doctor_name);

        }
    }
}
```

ViewPatientsFragment.java:

```
public class ViewPatientsFragment extends Fragment{
    private ArrayList<PatientModel> patientModelsList;
    public View_PatientList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerPatient;

    private PatientAdapter patientAdapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_patientlist, container, false);

        recyclerPatient=rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerPatient);
        patientModelsList=new ArrayList<>();
        patientAdapter=new PatientAdapter(patientModelsList);
        recyclerPatient.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerPatient.setAdapter(patientAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: please upload the class that uses it

Comment: @ATP Please have a look

Comment: How do you insert values to array?

Comment: `patientModelsList` is empty...

Comment: @ATP Layout data want to show the data

Comment: You cannot just show the layout in the recyclerview with an empty array.. u need to insert some data to the recycler array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not inserting anything to the array as you can see, you initialize the array and then put it into the adapter.

```
patientModelsList=new ArrayList<>(); <-- EMPTY
patientAdapter=new PatientAdapter(patientModelsList); <-- SENDING AN EMPTY LIST

--What you need--
patientModelsList.add(YOUR OBJECT HERE)
patientModelList.add(YOUR OBJECT HERE)
--And then call--
patientAdapter=new PatientAdapter(patientModelsList);
```

What you need to do is to add items in the array before sending it to the adapter, or have a method in the adapter like `insertItems()` and you pass the data, remember to make a

```
list.clear()
list.addAll(items)
notifyDataSetChanged()
```